# Find the value of constant K in line.

Tags: constants

Three points have coordinates $A (0, 7)$ $B (8, 3)$ and $C (3k, k)$.  Find the value of the constant $k$ for which:

i) $C$ lies on the line that passes through $A$ and $B$.

So what I did was that I firstly found the gradient.  $y2-y1/x2-x1$.  = $m = -1/2$.

Now I write it in the equation: $y = -1/2x + 7$.

The answer mentions that I must replace both the $y$ in the equation, and the $x$ in the equation with $3k$.  Why do I have to do this?  Why $3k$?  I am unable to understand the purpose of why this is being placed in there to complete the question?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What AlgortihmsX said. Pluggin in to the system of equations yields $k=-\frac{1}{2}*3k+7$. You can then solve for k.

Answer (score 1):

You are solving the system of equations $y=k$, $x=3k$, and $y=-\frac1 2x+7$.